# Referencing ids within screenmanager object

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to get my head around screenmanager, in particular referencing objects within.

I used to use this to set a value:

```
class Widgets(Widget)
    pass

w = Widgets()
w.ids.MyTitle.text = 'something'
```

Now I have this:

```
class Widgets(Screen)
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen)
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Widgets(name='main'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))
```

How do I reference MyTitle now? I've tried all sorts of combos such as:

```
sm.ids.main.MyTitle.text =
sm.main.MyTitle.text =
sm.main.ids.MyTitle.text =
```

.... but not getting it! Can someone put me out of my misery? Is there an easy way of browsing through the sm object or iterating through it maybe?

EDIT: Adding minimal running version:

minimal.kv:

```
# File name: minimal.py
#:kivy 1.8.0

<Widgets>
    Button:
        id: MyTitle
        text: 'hello'

<SettingsScreen>:
    Button:
        id: Other
        text: 'settings'
```

minimal.py:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App


class Widgets(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class myApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        global sm
        sm.ids['main'].ids['MyTitle'].text = 'changed' # <-- this fails

Builder.load_file("minimal.kv")

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Widgets(name='main'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve]? As such your code won't run. It also matters where the ids are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a screen from `ScreenManager`, use [`get_screen`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.get_screen):

```
sm.get_screen('main').ids.MyTitle.text = 'changed'
```

Also, you may construct your app so:
kv file:

```
# File name: minimal.py
#:kivy 1.8.0
ScreenManager:
    Widgets:
        name: 'main'
    SettingsScreen:
        name: 'settings'

<Widgets>:
    Button:
        id: MyTitle
        text: 'hello'

<SettingsScreen>:
    Button:
        id: Other
        text: 'settings'
```

and in the python file:

```
sm=Builder.load_file(..)

class my12App(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.get_screen('main').ids.MyTitle.text = 'changed'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html) you access an `id` like you would any dictionary key:

```
widget.ids['MyTitle']
```

Because [`ScreenManager`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html?highlight=screenmanager#module-kivy.uix.screenmanager) in itself derives from `Widget`, and a given widget maintains [a list of widgets it is aware of](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/widgets.html), you probably need something like:

```
sm.ids[0].ids['MyTitle'].text
```

However this is hard to say without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). One thing you could do is:

```
for id in sm.ids:  # Iterate through all widgets in ids
    print(id)  # Get the string representation of that widget
```

As a side note, this:

```
class Widgets(Screen)
    pass
```

... will probably cause confusion, because you're extending `Widget` with `Widgets` (via an intermediate class `Screen`). OOP suggests that a subclass of a class should be a more specific form of the class. So, a `Screen` is a **type** of `Widget`. But `Widgets` is really some **number** of `Widgets`.

Comment: This gives me KeyError: 'main'... I'm working on a Minimal version, but it's confusing me having ripped out most of my code... am having to get right back to basics!

Comment: I recommend using the REPL to test your intuition. Also, see my update.

Comment: I've added the REPL in but it doesn't return anything. If I change it to just print(sm.ids) it returns an empty dictionary!?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately neither the code in the question, nor the one in the accepted answer worked for me, and I'm unsure as to how exactly it is *supposed* to work. My interpretation of it is, that OP wanted to change a property of a widget (a Button) inside of one Screen based on a callback from another Screen. The below code is a *complete* MWE doing that:

```py
# File name: minimal.py
#:kivy 2.0.0

ScreenManager:
  FoobarScreen:
    name: 'foobar'
  Widgets:
    name: 'widgets'

<FoobarScreen>:
  Button:
    id: lalala
    text: 'lalala'

<Widgets>:
  Button:
    id: lololo
    text: 'lololo'
```

(`minimal.kv`)

```py
import kivy

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

class FoobarScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Widgets(Screen):
    pass

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.get_screen('widgets').ids.lololo.text = 'changed'
        self.root.current = 'widgets'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sm=Builder.load_file('minimal.kv')
    myApp().run()
```

(`minimal.py`)